# method to show 3 divs inside another div does not display properly in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I need to have 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another container div. I have managed to do this by CSS like given below.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}

.labelQuestion {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 99%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  height: 115px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  height: 115px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  height: 115px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
```

As seen here, rightmost div is given as the second div. This works very well.

But in the mobile view, these 3 divs are stacked. So the div which has to shown on the bottom (BLUE) is in the middle of the stack. How do I show these divs stacked in the order in mobile resolution- NAIL, PINK , BLUE

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just set the correct order in HTML?

Comment: this is to set 3 divs aligned in a container div

Answer (score -1):

i think float cannot be used for this, 
you can use flexbox and order

```
.inline{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}


.right{
  order:3
}

.left{
  order:1
}

.center{
  order:2
}
```

Comment: this is correct but OP wants them to show like that in mobile, your code will show them like that always.

Comment: yes that is true, but op wants different order for desktop and mobile.

Comment: hm as it seems no, looked different in the jsfiddle what I could recall. Sorry :)